# List indentation bug in edit-question

Tags: bug

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36692927/3429430), you can see that the last line `How does JavaScript internally creates automatic prototypes?` is indented. Now, if you click on **Edit**, then in live preview of the question, it shows no indentation.

I think it is a bug.

Comment: Not really a bug. This was before the [CommonMark migration](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/289905) and this post was excluded from migration.

Comment: off-topic: quirky question, nice find. It is a poster example of how a question looks like it should be closed (too broad / unfocused since it asks 4 questions). But if you really take the effort to look, it is not asking 4 questions. It is explaining quite carefully what is unknown about prototypes by posing it as a questionnaire. Which led to some awesome answers. It's nice to see a success like this from time to time.